# Running Solr on Azure Web Apps

Tags: java, azure, solr, azure-web-app-service

I have tried to run it in azure web app, but it doesn't work.

Here is my configuration. Maybe someone know how achieve this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="%HOME%\site\wwwroot\webapps\solr-6.0.0\bin\solr.cmd"
        arguments="start -p %HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%"
        startupTimeLimit="20"
        startupRetryCount="2"
        stdoutLogEnabled="true">
     <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="JAVA_HOME" value="D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Here is the Error Message:

The handle could not be opened
during redirection of handle 0.
The handle could not be opened
during redirection of handle 0.

ERROR: Java 1.8 or later is required to run Solr. Current Java version is:

Comment: You write value="D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73", this is your local address, not java home address on azure. Java has been installed on azure app environment. As far as I know, its current version is 1.7

Comment: Same thing on Service Fabric

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways for setting up the Java version on Azure WebApp.

1. Configuring the `web.config` file in the Kudu Console via the url `https://<your-webapp-name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole` as your said. However, please set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable with the value `D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_73` if your webapp not enable 64-bit for the option `PLATFORM` of Azure portal, see the figures below.

Fig 1. The `Platform` option of the tab `CONFIGURE` on Azure old portal
[image]

Fig 2. The `PLATFORM` option of the `Appication settings` on Azure new portal
[image]

2. Directly setting up in the `Application settings` on Azure new portal, please see the figure below and refer to [the blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azureossds/2015/05/08/running-java8-on-azure-web-apps/).

Fig 3. The `Java version` option of the `Application settings` on Azure new portal
[image]

---

**Update**

[image]

You can try to add the line below at the line 65.

```
set "JAVA_HOME=D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"
```

Comment: JAVA Home is already set. My value in the web.config is copied from this parameter value. echo %JAVA_HOME% is my value from above

Comment: @user3111087 You can try to use the Kudu Console to find the different versions of Java via commands `cd` & `ls`.

Comment: there are other versions too, but I need Java 8. And JAVA 8 is installed and JAVA_HOME is set.

Comment: @user3111087 I reviewed the `solr.cmd` file that you need to set the `JAVA_HOME` alone, please see my updated content.

Comment: I think the problem is not JAVA_HOME the PRoblem is that he can't extract the JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION IF !JAVA_MAJOR_VERSION! LSS 8 (
  set "SCRIPT_ERROR=Java 1.8 or later is required to run Solr. Current Java version is: !JAVA_VERSION_INFO!"
  goto err
)

Comment: no im stucking with this. Didn't find a solution with that. It would be great if this is possible since I can avoid running it on virtual instance,

Comment: @user3111087 I suggest that you can refer to the practice https://github.com/MSOpenTech/Windows-Azure-Solr to run solr on Azure CloudService. Or I think you can try the Azure Search service, please see https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/search/.